# For the same font style, how to resolve the difference between MAC and Windows font width and height?

Tags: css, compatibility, element-ui

[image]

In windows:
[image]

In mac:
[image]

The MAC and Windows console views are both 139px wide and 100% page size.
How do you get MAC and Windows font widths to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-length or max-width.